# GCP Dataflow There was a problem refreshing your credentials

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to create a dataflow in Java with Gradle. I've created a gradle task to upload the job to GCP via the `DataflowRunner` and set my credentials via `environment "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "....json"`, but when I view the job, all I see is:

```
Workflow failed. Causes: There was a problem refreshing your credentials. Please check: 
1. Dataflow API is enabled for your project. 
2. There is a robot service account for your project: 
service-[project number]@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
should have access to your project. 
If this account does not appear in the permissions tab for your project, contact Dataflow support.
```

I've already made sure the dataflow API is enabled for my project and that the service account exists and has `editor` and `Cloud Dataflow Service Agent` roles. I've tested with my code and the sample code on the `getting started` page, same issue.

Comment: Hi Ben, glad to have you here. You seek advice on a failing gradle job? Include the source you used (obviously no credentials) in your question and your chances of getting an answer grow

Comment: The gradle task succeeds, but the job fails when it starts to run on GCP Dataflow. I'm just following the code and steps on the Dataflow [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven)

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be triggerd if the Compute Engine default service account in the Google Cloud project is disabled:[image]

The status should show a green tick.

Answer (score 0):

When you first use Dataflow in a new GCP project, you need to enable the API (Step 3 in the Quickstart), it could take few minutes. During this step a couple of [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#security_and_permissions_for_pipelines_on_google_cloud_platform) are created:

*Cloud Dataflow service account:* `service-<project-number>@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.

*Controller service account:* `<project-number>-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

The first account is the one in the error. I would think that you have not enabled the Dataflow API or you executed the job while the API was being enabled. As you mentioned you verified this, the nex step is checking if the default service accounts were modified, let's say, they were recreated or the default permissions changed. These revisions also apply for the Controller service account.

In addition, please don't forget to assign [the proper permissions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#example_role_assignment) to the account that execute the Dataflow job.

**UPDATE:**

If the issue persists, it is probable that the service accounts were corrupted somehow, in which case, it is recommended to create a new GCP project with fresh service accounts or [Contact Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/contact).

Comment: Thanks for the help! Hmm, I see the `Cloud Dataflow service account`, but I do not see the `Controller service account`

Comment: Can you check if the [Compute Engine API](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux) is enabled (Step 3 in the link)? The default Controller service account is created by default when you enable the Compute Engine API. Is it possible that it was removed?

Comment: Yeah, the Compute Engine API is enabled. I think I see it, it has the pattern `service-<project-number>@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com`

Comment: Am I missing any permissions for the Dataflow service account? I've got `Compute Viewer`, `Dataflow Admin`, `Dataflow Developer`, `Cloud Dataflow Service Agent`, `Owner`, `Pub/Sub Admin`, `Storage Admin`, and `Storage Object Admin`

Comment: You mentioned you are following the [QuickStart](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-java-maven) and you get the same issue, what is the result of following the same guide in a new project? Since the issue persist even after the validations above, I think that something happened with the service accounts and with this test we will be able to narrow down the issue. In a new project I was be able to execute the job example described in the QuickStart.

Comment: I think something got screwed up with the project I was using. I created a fresh project and re-did all of the steps and got it working.

Comment: Great, I have updated my answer in case it help others.